# Entity Framework 6.0 SQL-first synch with database without .edmx?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, model, entity-framework-6

I have a database with some tables for school related project and I have a model with EF 6.0 SQL-first approach. I need to update the database with a new table & update an existing table with a new column. The twist is: I don’t have any *.edmx file.
How can I update the model without it? If it is impossible, then how can I generate *.edmx without interrupting the existing model?

Answer (score 1):

Entities are essentially POCOs, so you really just need to update your schema and update the entity classes to match. For new entities if the project is not using an edmx then it should either be using classes extending `EntityTypeConfiguration` or setting things up with the modelBuilder on the `OnModelCreating` event in the DbContext.

EF can resolve most general mappings using convention, so adding a column to a table usually just means adding the property to the entity. Mapping only comes into play when you want to change a columns naming, handle type casting differences, or use identity/computed columns. For new entities it can also use convention, but commonly there would be config used for the Table name, PK name, and things like Identity columns, plus navigation properties for related entities.